# In Foundation, how can I call a Modal after a submit button sends the data to another script

Tags: php, jquery, zurb-foundation

I saw foundation has a nice way of showing a pop up msg box, called Modal. Like to assign it to a button and done.

Now, I have assigned a modal to a form submit button. When a user click the submit button, modal pops up BUT it doesn't not let me to send the values to the another .php script (form action) where I have to capture the variables.

Can anyone please tell me how can I achieve that?

I want to show the pop up after the form is submitted saying "Thank you for the registration".

I tried a lot, can anyone please point me in right direction.

Comment: please post the relevant code of what you tried so far + the foundation version number. It seems you fired a `reveal` modal on click of you submit button. This will not send any form data anywhere. So Please post your attemp.

Comment: Yes that's what I did. But I want to the reveal model to appear after I've sent the data.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of JQuery, it's actually quite simple, for my case, I needed all form to reveal the modal on submit.

1) Add the Modal div on your view, I put mine on my footer.php

```
<div id="submitModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
  <p>Please wait while your request is being processed.</p>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

2) Add this somewhere on your script.js file

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    $('#submitModal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
});
```

If you need to reveal the modal on a particular form, just replace the 'form' with your form id

Enjoy :)